# Generating Unique Random Numbers in Arrays C++

Tags: c++, arrays, random

I have coded an array with 3 random integers inside of it. The key is though that I want the 3 random integers to be different than each other (unique random numbers). My problem is that even when the numbers are unique, I still get a 'bad' reading from them. I seeded my random numbers with time(NULL) and because of this I put a Sleep(x) function in between each declaration to increase variety in numbers. The following code is all of my code inside my main() function. For testing purposes, I didn't include a break statement in my code so I could test the program over and over.

```
srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

while(true)
{
    //Generate 3 numbers
    int a = rand() % 7 + 1;
    Sleep(1000);
    int b = rand() % 8 + 1;
    Sleep(1000);
    int c = rand() % 9 + 1;
    int array[3] = { a , b , c };

    //Check the numbers to make sure none of them equal each other
    if( (array[a] == array[b]) || (array[a] == array[c]) || (array[b] == array[c]) )
    {
        //Print all numbers
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            cout << array[x] << endl;
        cout << "bad" << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }
    else
    {
        //Print all numbers
        for(int x = 0; x < 3; x++)
            cout << array[x] << endl;
        cout << "good" << endl;
        system("pause");
        system("cls");
    }   
}
system("pause");
return 0;
```

Comment: the `Sleep` calls don't change the number that's generated. the time is only checked when `srand(time(NULL))` is run.

Comment: Note that the call to `srand` is what seeds the random number generator. A separate seed isn't used every time you call `rand`. So, the `Sleep`s make no sense.

Comment: To generate unique numbers one of the most simple/reliable ways for a relatively small fixed set is to create an array of the *allowed* values, then shuffle the array and take the first N values. For example, given an array {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} shuffle it and then use arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] etc. There are many questions/answers that are suitable for and recommend this (Fisher-Yates) shuffling approach.

Answer (score 5):

The problem with the current check is it checks at the *indices* represented by the random values, and not the random values themselves, which are the first 3 elements.

Simply replace

```
if( (array[a] == array[b]) || (array[a] == array[c]) || (array[b] == array[c]) )
```

with

```
if( (array[0] == array[1]) || (array[0] == array[2]) || (array[1] == array[2]) )
```

or just

```
if(a == b || a == c || b == c)
```

Comment: (Make sure to add a written explanation.)

Answer (score 0):

It appears you're using [`Sleep`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686298%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), a Windows-specific function that has nothing to do with the C library. [`srand`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/srand) affects the sequence returned by `rand()` which is repeatable if `srand()` is given the same seed.

Secondly, the range of random numbers that you are storing in `a`, `b` and `c` can possibly cause out of bounds array access in this line here:

```
if( (array[a] == array[b]) || (array[a] == array[c]) || (array[b] == array[c]) )
```

`array` only has 3 elements, yet the values in `a`, `b` and `c` can be higher than that.

Since you are using C++, consider taking advantage of the C++ standard library.

First create a vector of a specified size, and use [`std::iota`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) to fill it with values in the range [0, 10).

```
std::vector<int> v(10);
std::iota(v.begin(), v.end(), 0);
```

Then we use [`std::random_shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) to reorder the values.

```
std::random_shuffle (v.begin(), v.end());
```

And pick the top three values:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i)
    std::cout << v[i] << " ";
```

Comment: This is very interesting code. It intrigues me. I only have 1 question. When you said "pick the top three values" do you mean the first 3 that are at the front of the shuffled array or the largest numbers?

Comment: @user3742063 The first one.

Answer (score 0):

1. Like everyone else said, the sleeps don't do anything.
2. The shuffle idea isn't great. Its slower than regenerating the numbers until you get unique ones, and it doesn't scale very well. If you wanted your range of allowed numbers to be large the shuffle would become prohibitively expensive.

I would do something like this:

```
int a = rand() % 7 + 1;

int b = rand() % 8 + 1;
while( a == b ) 
   b = rand() % 8 + 1;

int c = rand() % 9 + 1;
while(( a == c ) || ( b == c )) 
   c = rand() % 9 + 1;

int array[3] = { a , b , c };
```

3. Your check for "bad values" should be:

   if ( ( a == b) || ( a == c ) || ( b == c ) )

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner! I have no idea why I didn't think of this. Thank you very much.